# Inserting a ContentControl into a chart

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js

I'm trying to insert a ContentControl into a chart in MS Word. I'm using the same code I'm using for inserting ContentControls to an empty selection (part of the document which does not contain anything except plain text) but it's not working the way I intended it too. I've browsed a couple of issues here on SO, but the solutions did not work for me.

This is the code:

```
return window.Word.run(context => {

    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    var cc = range.insertContentControl();
    var ccRange = cc.insertHtml(content, 'replace');

    // do other stuff ...
});
```

If I leave it like this, the chart gets completely replaced by new content. If I do `cc.insertHtml(content, 'end');` it does not get replaced, but adds the new ContentControl to end of the chart, which is OK.

What I don't understand is:

- why is the chart replaced with new content if I've inserted a new ContentControl to the selection?
- how to properly do this and insert a ContentControl inside a chart (to annotate labels, chart title etc.)?
- if the above is possible, can I check whether I'm in a chart (or some other object) or in an empty selection (on which I can continue using the code above)?

Comment: It's not clear WHY you'd want a content control *in* a chart? But in any case, that's not something that's supported by Word. Try it as a user - it's not possible. Charts are not part of Word, they come from Excel, and know nothing of content controls...

Comment: @CindyMeister it's an add in for inserting references and bibliography into documents (they're all content controls), changing their styles based on the publication you're writing them for etc. Some users requested the possibility to insert references to charts. Technically, they can just insert a reference manually, without the content control, but then it's not recognized by the add in.

Comment: Do they just need to reference the chart - the fact that the chart is there? The entire chart should be able to go *into* a content control. Or a bookmark.

Comment: @CindyMeister referencing a chart works great if I just insert the reference to the end of the content control that wraps around the chart. I will try to offer that as a solution (surely it will cover some use cases), but there was a question about referencing some text inside the chart itself. It's probably a very rare use case.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible, unless you have them change the Alt Text or name the text box with a name your code can recognize and pick up? Text boxes on a Chart are MSO Shapes, same as text boxes on a Word document.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!